# Simulate expiring SSL certificate

Tags: ssl

I'm looking for a service online, able to simulate an expiring SSL certificate. I know about badssl.com, but that only seems to include an expired certificate. What I'm looking to do is to call an endpoint with a certificate expiring in something like 5 days. Possible?

Comment: You can create one locally and use `openssl s_server` to simulate a server using it.

Comment: Maybe create this as an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about an online service tailored to your needs (you could also try to contact `badssl.com` and ask them if they would be willing to add your test case, as it may profit others too), but locally you can run `openssl s_server` and configure it to use any local certificate you would have created to be in the situation you need to test.

From its manual:

> The s_server command implements a generic SSL/TLS server which listens for connections on a given port using SSL/TLS.

and:

> s_server can be used to debug SSL clients. To accept connections from a web browser the command:

```
    openssl s_server -accept 443 -www
```

> can be used for example.

Otherwise, if you are outside of the world wide web world:

> If a connection request is established with an SSL client and neither the -www nor the -WWW option has been used then normally any data received from the client is displayed and any key presses will be sent to the client.

(and follows a list of special keys for special operations).